# My JS npm package causes 'Could not find a declaration file for module' error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, npm-publish

I published an npm package that is JavaScript. It works fine, but there are always three dots in front of the name when you import it into another app and an error message that says:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'my-npm-package'
```

How do i create a declaration file? The package is not TypeScript. I've never used TypeScript before.

Here is how may file tree looks:

```
index.js
package.json
README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this command to generate a `index.d.ts` file:

```
tsc --declaration --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly index.js
```

> NOTE: if you don't have `typescript` installed in your system, you need it for this command to work:
>
> ```
> npm install -g typescript
> ```

also you can add a `types` section to your `package.json` file to point to your declarations file.

```json
{
...
"main": "index.js",
"types": "index.d.ts",
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I run the 'tsc --declaration --allowJs --emitDeclarationOnly index.js' command every time I add a new function or make changes to the package?

Comment: If your functions input or output types are changing yes you need to run it again.
Or you can attach it to your build script in `package.json` so everytime you want to make a new release it will be generated too.